# Dependant Dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project in order to be able to make a bespoke customizer for PC hardware in order to ensure everything is compatible. I am able to make the dropdowns and have validated that they can both be submitted successfully, although I need to pull 2 values and store them in 2 variables so I can use them to A (Store the ID of the CPU) and B (Store the appropriate socket).

```php
<select id="pcat" name="pcat" onchange="autoSubmit();">
    <option value="">-- Select Parent Category --</option>
    <?php
    //select parent categories. parent categories are with parent_id=0
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cpus` ORDER BY `cpus`.`CPUName` ASC";
        $result = dbQuery($sql);
        while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
            echo ("<option value=\"{$row['CPUID']}\" " . ($pmenu == $row['CPUID'] ? " selected" : "") . ">{$row['CPUName']} ({$row['Cores']} Cores | {$row['Threads']}  Threads | {$row['Frequency']}GHz)</option>");
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

I would like to also add in the ability to store a variable called $sockets which would relate to the row called 'CPUSoc' in my database implementation.

Comment: I suggest searching on Google first how to make a dependant dropdown with PHP, JavaScript (Ajax) and MySQL. There should be tutorials out there that explains the basics

Comment: Already tried to use Google but I haven't been able to find appropriate articles and the ones I have found don't cover what I require (or at least from what I have read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself in a kind of... Strangely easy but stupid workaround. All I needed to do in order to pull out an additional variable was to have another query running with the CPUID like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cpus WHERE CPUID = $cpumenu";
$result = dbQuery($sql);
while ($row = dbFetchAssoc ($result)){
    ($socket = $row['CPUSoc']);
}
```

And then using the stored $socket variable in the following query to use the stored result in the next query:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `motherboards` WHERE Socket = '$socket' ORDER BY `motherboards`.`MoboName` ASC";
```